# VBA Error 91 , after calling Sub within the main Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Module that is trying to get all occurrences of a date in column G in one sheet. After finding the row of the occurrence, I'm saving other values from the sheet on the same row from different columns, i.e. `bldg`, and `room`, and `numPerson`.

What I'm trying to do after that is to get the call a function with the date, `numPerson`, `bldg` and `room` as arguments. The function `FillDateCapacitiesInOccupancySheet` should go to a different sheet and search column B for the `bldg`, get that row, then look for the room on the same row and place the `numPpl` on the row under the correct column for the date that was given. In the following code I get an Error 91 on the `Loop While` statement if I remove

```vb
If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "No Found Cell Address", vbInformation
   Exit Sub
End If
```

The click function works fine if I remove the call to the function `FillDateCapacitiesInOccupancySheet`, but otherwise I get an error. Either the `FoundCell` or `myRange` is empty but I'm not sure why or how to fix it.

```vb
Sub ConflictButton_Click()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range
    Dim targetColumn As Range
    Dim beginningDate As String, stringDate As String, month As String, day As String, year As String
    Dim dates As Date
    Dim occWS As Worksheet, excepWS As Worksheet
    Dim beginningDateCell As Range, addDatesCells As Range, FindDateRow As Range
    Dim datesArray(1 To 7) As Date, stringDatesArray(1 To 7) As String
    Dim lLoop As Long, findRowNumber As Long
    Dim tempMonth As String, tempDay As String
    Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    
    'Copy Building, Room, and Max Capacity Columns from sheet Table to sheet OccupancyByDate
    Set sourceColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table").Columns("B:D").Rows("3:500")
    Set targetColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OccupancyByDate").Columns("B:D").Rows("3:500")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
    
    
    'open FindConflictDates Form
    FindConflictDatesForm.Show
    
    'Set OccupancyByDate sheet Column E Row 2 (Column Header) to the Week Starting Date,
    'get the week beginning string from what was saved from the FindConflictDatesForm
    
    If WeekBeginningString <> "" Then
        beginningDate = WeekBeginningString
        WeekBeginningDate = CDate(beginningDate) ' convert String to Date
    
        Set occWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OccupancyByDate")
        Set excepWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Telework Exceptions")

       ' Fill the 7 dates into header in OccupanyByDate sheet Columns E - K row 2
    
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 1
        For j = 5 To 11 ' From column E(5) to K (11)
           dates = WeekBeginningDate - Weekday(WeekBeginningDate, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) + i 
           occWS.Cells(2, j).Value = Format(dates, "dd-mmm-yyyy") ' write dates to OccByDate sheet
           'Save dates to datesArray
           datesArray(i) = dates
           
            stringDate = CStr(dates) ' convert date to string
            If Mid(stringDate, 2, 1) <> "/" Then ' 2 digit month
                tempMonth = Left(stringDate, 2)
            Else
                tempMonth = Left(stringDate, 1) ' 1 digit month
            month = GetMonthAbbreviation(tempMonth)
            End If
            
            If Left(Right(stringDate, 7), 1) <> "/" Then '2 digit day
                day = Left(Right(stringDate, 7), 2)
            Else
                day = Left(Right(stringDate, 6), 1) ' 1 digit day
              '  day = Mid(stringDate, 4, 2)
            End If
            
            year = Right(stringDate, 4)
            stringDatesArray(i) = day & "-" & month & "-" & year
           
           i = i + 1 ' Add 1 to increment date of week
        Next j
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
        ' Search for dates on the TW Exception Sheet
        Dim numPerson As Long, Bldg As String, Room As String, foundDate As String
        
        numPerson = 0
        
        
        For i = LBound(datesArray) To UBound(datesArray)
            'Search for datesArray(i) on TW Exceptions sheet
            Set myRange = excepWS.Range("G:G")
            Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.count)
            Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=stringDatesArray(i), after:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlValues)
            
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then ' if value found in column
                FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
                findRowNumber = FoundCell.Row  'get row number of the found date in the column on TW Excep sheet
                
                foundDate = FoundCell.Text 'get text value of first occurence of new date found in column
                      
                Do ' Find additional occurences of date in the sheet column
            
                    findRowNumber = FoundCell.Row
                    
                    If FoundCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = 1 Then
                        numPerson = 1
                    End If
                    If FoundCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 1 Then
                        numPerson = 1
                    End If
               
                    Bldg = FoundCell.Offset(0, 3).Text
                    Room = FoundCell.Offset(0, 4).Text
                    
                    FillDateCapacitiesInOccupancySheet foundDate, numPerson, Bldg, Room 'if i remove this line I don't get an error
                    
                    Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell)
                
                    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "No Found Cell Address", vbInformation
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                  
                Loop While (FoundCell.Address <> FirstFound)
            
            End If
        Next i 'Get next dateArray value
    End If 'End if WeekBeginningString <> ""
 
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub FillDateCapacitiesInOccupancySheet(fndDate As String, numPpl As Long, Buildg As String, Rm As String)
    Dim occWS As Worksheet
    Dim FndCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myNewRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    Dim foundBldg As String
    Dim findRowNumber As Long, count As Long
    Dim dateOffset As Integer
    Dim FirstFound As String
    
    count = 0
    
    Set occWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OccupancyByDate")
 
    Set myNewRange = occWS.Range("B:B") ' search in building column
    Set LastCell = myNewRange.Cells(myNewRange.Cells.count)
    Set FndCell = myNewRange.Find(what:=Buildg, after:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not FndCell Is Nothing Then ' if value found in column
        FirstFound = FndCell.Address
        findRowNumber = FndCell.Row  'get row number of the found building in the column on OccByDate sheet
                
        foundBldg = FndCell.Text 'get text value of first occurence of new building found in column
                          
        Do ' Find additional occurences of date in the sheet column
            findRowNumber = FndCell.Row
             
            If FndCell.Offset(0, 1).Text = Rm Then ' if room passed into function equals room for the building
                'Find the date column for the date passed into function
                For j = 5 To 11 ' From column E(5) to K (11)
                    If occWS.Cells(2, j).Text = fndDate Then 
                        dateOffset = j - 2
                        count = FndCell.Offset(0, dateOffset).Value + numPpl
                        ' write count to cell
                        FndCell.Offset(0, dateOffset).Value = count
                    End If 
                Next j     
            End If
                    
            Set FndCell = myNewRange.FindNext(FndCell)
            
        Loop While (FndCell.Address <> FirstFound)
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cells.Find() Raises “Runtime Error 91: Object Variable or With Block Not Set”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29102052/11683)

Comment: One of the comments says "'Search for datesArray(i) on TW Exceptions sheet" but the actual Find command says: `myRange.Find(what:=stringDatesArray(i)` Depending on the actual values in `MyRange`, this may or may not be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I get an Error 91 on the `Loop While` statement*

Here:

> ```
>     Set FndCell = myNewRange.FindNext(FndCell)
>     
> Loop While (FndCell.Address <> FirstFound)
> ```

If that `Range.FindNext` call doesn't find anything, `FndCell` is `Nothing` when the `While` condition gets evaluated, and that would be where error 91 is being raised; the `If Not FndCell Is Nothing Then` parent block means nothing as soon as `FndCell` is re-assigned.

You *need* to bail out when `FndCell` is `Nothing`. Consider using `Exit Do` for this:

```
    If FndCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
Loop While FndCell.Address <> FirstFound
```

Only exiting the smaller scope *conveys intent* better than exiting the entire procedure scope here, I find - even if all that's left to execute [for now] is an `End Sub` statement.

Consider declaring `j` and having `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, too!

Comment: Thank you. Follow up.   I finally got the internal sub to do what i wanted, but after returning from the procedure call when FoundCell is nothing, I can't seem to get the row of  the next date from the Exception Sheet if the date is the same as the previously found one. I want to be able to get the row even if the date is a duplicate.