# Find next non-empty cell in column

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a column of data (player names) that I pasted from another Excel file. Cell `A2` has the first player name and then there are several blank rows (the number of blank rows isn't the same for every roster sheet), and I am trying to determine the row number of the next non-empty cell with:

```
nextPlayerRow = rosterSh.Columns("A").Find(What = "*", after:=rosterSh.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues).row
```

where `nextPlayerRow` is declared as an `Integer`. This, however, returns a Runtime Error 91.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cells.Find() Raises "Runtime Error 91: Object Variable or With Block Not Set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102052/cells-find-raises-runtime-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-not-set)

Answer (score 0):

Run-time error 91 is Object variable not set.  Possibly either you have not done a set to initialize rosterSh, or your .find is finding nothing, and therefore unable to return .row.

When you use the .find method, (or any time you need a property of a method) you should first retrieve the object with a Set, and then check for the existence of the object, before trying to access one of its properties as in:

```
Set nextPlayerCell = rosterSh.Columns("A").Find(What = "*", after:=rosterSh.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not nextPlayerCell is nothing then
    nextPlayerRow = nextPlayerCell.row
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Find` you could use `End(xlDown)`.

```
nextPlayerRow = rosterSh.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```